# Get 'import' error when trying to import .rake file in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, require

I have been trying to import a .rake file into my controller using import 'file.rake' but I seem to get an error saying undefined method 'import' for Main:object. I have tried to look online for any documentation on how to use import but I can't find anything. Does anyone have a solution or have come across this error before?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you give a little more context to what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you trying to do, because loading a rake file in the controller looks suspicious.

Comment: On top of which, `import` isn't a method in Ruby's core - it exists in the `Rake` library to allow rakefile includes.

Comment: My controller controls my form that I fill out and I am trying to activate the .rake file once the controller is finished, also I will be passing an id of the new customer to the .rake file from the controller telling the .rake file its a new customer. 
So I was trying to import the .rake file into the controller so I could pass the id to it and run it.

Comment: What is your rakefile doing? It sounds like you might be trying to do something in a very unusual way, and there's probably a better way.

Comment: My rake file is navigating to a website and logging into that website using the information from the controller and depending on whether its a new customer or an existing one it downloads certain files from that website. If new customer is goes back 2 years and gets the data if existing customer it only downloads one days of data. The controller populates the database with the credentials of the new customer and I want to the .rake file to automatically run once the form is filled out so it downloads the customers data for them

Comment: If you are wanting a background task, you should look into Sidekiq, Resque, or DelayedJobs. Rake tasks should not be run through your website -- they are maintenance tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're probably going about this the wrong way. Why is that functionality in a Rakefile?

Rake is Ruby's equivalent of `make` - it's designed to handle software tasks with dependencies, like building an app, or packaging an releasing a Rubygem. Even [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rake_%28software%29) has a pretty good description of what it's for, or see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2881860/93884) for a link dump.

What you've described sounds like it's normal Rails stuff - take web input, act on it, interface with database. I'd seriously consider rewriting your Rake tasks inside Rails.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you can read about here: [Run rake task in controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170148/run-rake-task-in-controller)

But I really wouldn't recommend them. If you are finding a need to run some extra code within your application, breaking out to the console is not the way to do it. Write the code into your application, perhaps in a lib file, and call that instead.

You can even have your rake file call the same lib method so that you're DRY.

Add a code file to the lib folder, put all the logic in there

```
module ExtraActions
  def method_that_does_logins
    ...
  end
end
```

Include this in your controller:

```
UsersController < ApplicationController
  include ExtraActions

  def create
    ... #normal code
    method_that_does_logins
  end
end
```