# Calling rake task from controller on create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, rake, task

I have the following rake task:

**update_rank.rake**

```
task :build => :environment do
  Result.desc(:score).each_with_index do |result, position|
    result.update_attribute(:rank, position + 1)
  end
end
```

I want to call this task from the controller whenever a result is created. What is the best way to do this? Should i instead move this task into a model?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170148/run-rake-task-in-controller

Comment: Search for background task gems like `delayed_job`. What you're describing is an asynchronous process with a queue trigger. There are several such libraries already built and ready to use.