# Rails don't know how to build task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rakefile

I am attempting to scrape data from a website. I am running rake from index.html.erb

```
 <% Article.run_rake("fetch_games") %>
```

I have it defined in a .rb file. Here is article.rb

```
require 'rake'
require 'rubygems'
#load './lib/tasks/article_task.rake'

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

 def self.run_rake(fetch_games)
  Rails.root + "lib/tasks/article_task.rake"
  Rake::Task["fetch_games"].invoke
 end
end
```

And here is the rakefile itself: article_task.rake

```
desc "Fetch Games"
task :fetch_games => :environment do 

 require 'nokogiri'
 require 'open-uri'

 url = "http://espn.go.com/nba/schedule"
 data = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
 games = data.css('.responsive-table-wrap')

 games.each do |game|

 #check for a listing
 if !game.at_css("caption").nil?
    #Date
    puts game.at_css("caption").text
 else
    puts "No Listing"   
 end

 #check for the team name
 if !game.at_css(".team-name").nil?
    #Team name
    puts game.at_css(".team-name").text
 else
    puts "No Games Scheduled"
 end
    #empty
    puts ""
 end
end
```

When I run this from the terminal it pulls what I need. But when I try to run it through rails server it gives me this error:

[image: Runtime Error]

What am I doing wrong? New to ruby/rails btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went in another direction from the rake file. I defined it in articles controller and called it in `index.html.erb`. It now displays in the rails server.

articles_controller.rb

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

def index
    url = "http://espn.go.com/nba/schedule"
    data = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
    @games = data.css('.responsive-table-wrap')
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<% @games.each do |game| %>
        <% if !game.at_css("caption").nil? %>
          <%= game.at_css("caption").text %>
        <% else %>
          <%= 'No Games Sheduled' %>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
```

Answer (score 3):

We need to load_tasks before you run that. You comment out that line -

```
 load './lib/tasks/article_task.rake'
```

Do this -

```
  require 'rake'
  require 'rubygems'
  load './lib/tasks/article_task.rake'

  class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

    def self.run_rake(fetch_games)
      Rake::Task["fetch_games"].invoke
    end
  end
```

Comment: Tried this first. The new error is  `Don't know how to load 'environment'`

Comment: @Lilspree If environment is not available. Remove `environment` in task file for force task >>>>>   task :fetch_games do

Comment: I did this and I even tried loading the environment even though it should already be loaded. I don't get any errors when I run the above answer. I believe its running but just not displaying. Could it be because I am trying to display it from a `.html.erb` file?

Comment: Do `<%= Article.run_rake("fetch_games") %>` instead of `<% Article.run_rake("fetch_games") %>` for display in view file.

Answer (score 1):

I think this thread can help: [Run rake task in controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170148/run-rake-task-in-controller)

Apparently, you have to call something like that before you call your task:

```
NameOfYourApp::Application.load_tasks
```

Comment: That loads every task, I just want to load a specific one with `load './lib/tasks/article_task.rake'`

Answer (score 1):

Rather than go through the contortions needed to load up an invoke a Rake task, you could move the code into a separate unit and load it in the model (and the Rake task, if you need it).

```
module GameFetcher
  def fetch
    ...
  end
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend GameFetcher
  ...
end

Article.fetch
```

This also makes it easier to write a unit test for the `fetch` logic.