# calling a rails lib task from console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to run a lib task from the rails console. The lib task looks like follows:

```
class ImagesImport
 def initialize(param1)
  option
 end

 def option
  #auth_code
  options = { param2, param3 } # with key n value
  import(options)
 end

 def import(options)
  #data creating code
 end
end
```

I am trying to run the `import(options)` method. As per my knowledge, now all I need to do is go to the rails console and call:

```
ImagesImport.new('param1')
```

This is supposed to run the import task. But instead its creating some kind of object like follows:

```
#<ImagesImport:0x0000000a1bb868 param1 = "value">
```

Comment: are your returning any thing from task ? add logger to check how it is working

Comment: Not returning anything. trying to Creating records.

Comment: is data  created ? try to debug with `binding.pry` you will get better idea. are you aware about  gem `pry` ?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170148/run-rake-task-in-controller . I think this will be helpful for you.

Comment: What is `lib task`? Are you talking about `rake task`?

Comment: @Зелёный a script inside lib folder. Not rake task.

Comment: It's unclear what is you cant to do. The object you see is a class you're created.